# Query to fetch records from 2 diff table into 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 table like below :

1)

```
    Engine
    ======

ID     Title    Unit   Value
123    Hello    Inch   50
555    Hii      feet   60
```

2)

```
    Fuel
    =====

ID    Title     Value
123   test12     343
555   test5556   777
```

I want the select result in 2 columns as per the ID given (ID should be same in both tables) :

**Title** `-- This will get the (Title + Unit) from Engine table and only
 Title from Fuel table. Value`

**Value**`-- This will get Value from both tables.`

Result for ID = 123 is :

```
Title          Value

Hello(Inch)   50
test12        343
```

Any suggestion how I can get this in SQL server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your same data and the desired result, it appears that you want to use a `UNION ALL` to get the data from both tables:

```
select title+'('+Unit+')' Title, value
from engine
where id = 123
union all
select title, value
from fuel
where id = 123
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1bda7/8)

The result of the query is:

```
|       TITLE | VALUE |
-----------------------
| Hello(Inch) |    50 |
|      test12 |   343 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have a look at something like [Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/) and read up a little on JOINS

- [Join Fundamentals](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1667/sql-server-join-example/)
- [SQL Server Join Example](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1667/sql-server-join-example/)
- [SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/102805/SQL-Joins)

**EDIT**

Maybe then also look at

- [CASE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [+ (String Concatenation) (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx)
- [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Look at SQL JOINs: INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN etc

```
Select 
      e.ID, e.Title, e.Unit, e.Value, f.Title as FuelTitle, e.Value as FuelValue,
      e.Title+' '+e.Units As TitleAndUnits
From Engine e
Join Fuel f
On e.ID = f.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this w/o a join but with join it may be more optimal depending on other factors in your case.

Example w/o join:

```
select concat(t1.c1, ' ', t1.c2, ' ', t2.c1) col1, concat(t1.c3, ' ', t2.c3) col2 
from t1, t2
where t1.id = [ID] and t2.id = [ID]
```